# Calculate duration in R

Tags: r, duration

I wonder if there is an easy way to calculate the duration. I have a dataset where the a parameter, called `m`, varies between the values `-1` and `1` during time. I want to calculate:

1. The total duration (time in hours) of cases where `m=-1` and `m=1`
   respectively
2. How long is each period of cases where `m=-1` and `m=1` respectively is

   m<-c(1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

   Time <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1),   by                 = "1 hour")

Comment: It is definitely possible. Can you give a sample of your data so we can help you with that?

Comment: Have you converted your Time variable to proper format e.g. `df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time)` ? When it's done - you can simply subtract time variables to get difftime.

Comment: Add [reproducible sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: I´ve tried to add a sample, is it OK the way I did it? So much to learn...

Answer (score 2):

I'd use package data.table for "split-apply-combine" and identify the runs using `cumsum` and `diff`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="Time,    m
2015-01-01 00:00,    -1
2015-01-01 01:00,    -1
2015-01-01 02:00,    -1
2015-01-01 03:00,    1
2015-01-01 04:00,    1
2015-01-01 05:00,    1
2015-01-01 06:00,    1
2015-01-01 07:00,    1
2015-01-01 08:00,    -1
2015-01-01 09:00,    -1
2015-01-01 10:00,    -1
2015-01-01 11:00,    -1
2015-01-01 12:00,    1
2015-01-01 13:00,    1
2015-01-01 14:00,    1
2015-01-01 15:00,    -1", header = TRUE, sep =",")

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, Time := as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz = "GMT")]
DF[, run := cumsum(c(1, diff(m) != 0))]

DF1 <- DF[, list(m = unique(m), 
                 duration = difftime(max(Time), min(Time), unit = "min")), 
          by = run]
#   run  m duration
#1:   1 -1 120 mins
#2:   2  1 240 mins
#3:   3 -1 180 mins
#4:   4  1 120 mins
#5:   5 -1   0 mins

DF1[, sum(duration), by = m]
#    m  V1
#1: -1 300
#2:  1 360
```

Comment: Great! It took me sometime to understand this. Now I have studied more about the data.table package and I Think I understand. However, I would also compute the cumulative time of m=1 and m=-1 respectively, however I can´t figure out how to do. Do you have any suggestions?